# Zend Framework command line see errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm using a method outline by gregor ([Create cronjob with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143320/create-cronjob-with-zend-framework)) to create command line execution for parts of my application such as cron jobs, admin tasks, and the like. It works, however, no errors get reported when I create a new object that has not been defined (misspelling) and other such mistakes.

I would have thought that php would report an error, but it fails silently. What is the reason for this? Is there a better way to achieve my goal? Or how can I implement this so that I can see errors?

Many thanks!

Here is the code:

in public/index.php

```
if(!defined('RUN_APP') || RUN_APP == true)
{  
    $application->bootstrap()->run();
}
```

application/cron.php

```
define("RUN_APP",false);
require(realpath('/var/www/domain/public/index.php'));
$application->bootstrap();

//the rest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'll answer in case someone else is looking. I'm not sure why this is so but, putting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

at the top of your "cron.php" file does the trick. I guess you could throw a:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

in for good measure. The puzzling thing is that I get these errors when not using the command line and I do not have the above lines in my index.php or bootstrap.php. So they are being set somewhere else in the zend framework. Perhaps "phpSettings.display_errors = 1" in bootstrap has something to do with it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Errors are displayed in the main commandline program, but not if they fail to instantiate a Zend Model Object.  Your suggested fix does not work for me.   Thanks though.